# How to resold syntax error in insert sql query (Node js)

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sql-server, syntax-error

I am trying to Insert data into the MSSQL database, but there is a syntax error

***Code***

```
app.get('/PostItem', (req, res) => {
let post = ['test', 'tesa', 1];
let sql = 'INSERT INTO [dbo].[Item](ItemCode,ItemName,CreatedBy) VALUES (?,?,?)';
let query = con.query(sql, post, err => {
    if (err) {

        throw err
    }
    res.send('Item added');
})
```

});

**error**

this the error

(node:8584) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RequestError: Incorrect syntax near '?'.

[image]

**NOTE:** "database connection is work"

Comment: SQL Server doesn't use `?` for parameters

Comment: I change code without `?` and It's work

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't use `?`  then I change code like this and it works.

```
app.get('/PostItem', (req, res) => {
var post = ["'test'", "'test'", 1];
var sql = `INSERT INTO [dbo].[Item](ItemCode,ItemName,CreatedBy) VALUES (${post})`;
var query = con.query(sql, err => {
    if (err) {
        throw err
    }

    res.send('Item added');
 });  
});
```

Comment: Don't do interpolation, it's a recipe for SQL injection disaster, use proper named parameters `@ItemCode, @ItemName, @CreatedBy`